# Spring Maven Project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hey guys I am having a problem when I try to run this application. I do not receive a compilation error, just runtime ones. I think I am missing something but I am not sure, can someone help me understand where I've gone wrong? From what I can see the `sessionFactory` bean in the applicationContext.xml is not being created. Here is my code:

***Main***

```
package com.apress.flexjava.usermanager.business;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import com.apress.flexjava.usermanager.dao.UserDao;
import com.apress.flexjava.usermanager.model.User;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args){

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        UserDao userDao = (UserDao)context.getBean("userDao");
        List<User> users = userDao.findAll();
        for (User user : users) {
            System.out.println(user.getForename() + " " + user.getSurname());
        }
    }
}

______________________________________________________________________________________
```

***UserDao***

```
package com.apress.flexjava.usermanager.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.apress.flexjava.usermanager.model.User;

public interface UserDao {
    List<User> findAll();
}
__________________________________________________________________________________
```

***UserDaoSpringJdbcImpl***

```
package com.apress.flexjava.usermanager.dao.jdbc;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcDaoSupport;
import com.apress.flexjava.usermanager.dao.UserDao;
import com.apress.flexjava.usermanager.model.User;

public class UserDaoSpringJdbcImpl extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport implements UserDao{


public List<User> findAll(){
    String sql= "SELECT * FROM users";
    return getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query(sql, ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(User.class));  
    }
}

____________________________________________________________________________________
```

***User***

```
package com.apress.flexjava.usermanager.model;

public class User {
    private int userid;
    private String forename;
    private String surname;

    public User(){}

    public User(int userid, String forename, String surname){
        this.userid = userid;
        this.forename = forename;
        this.surname = surname; 
    }

    public User(String forename, String surname){   
        this.forename = forename;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public int getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(int userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getForename() {
        return forename;
    }

    public void setForename(String forename) {
        this.forename = forename;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}
_________________________________________________________________________________
```

***applicationContext.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- @Required processor -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


    <!-- Exception translation bean post processor -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
    <list>
    <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name= "driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name= "url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name= "username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name= "password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="UserDao" class="com.apress.flexjava.usermanager.dao.jdbc.UserDaoSpringJdbcImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name = "configLocation" value = "classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    <property name = "hibernateProperties">

    <value>
    hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect 
    hibernate.query.substitutions=true 'Y', false 'N'
    hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
    hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
    hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
    hibernate.show_sql=true 
    </value>

    </property>

    </bean>


</beans>

________________________________________________________________________________________
```

***jdbc properties***

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usermanager_test
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=password
_______________________________________________________________________________________
```

***pom.xml***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.apress.flexjava</groupId>
  <artifactId>usermanager</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>UserManager</name>

<dependencies> 
  <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.6</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>  
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.6</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies> 

</project>
____________________________________________________________________________
```

***Console Runtime Error:***

```
Apr 17, 2012 11:51:49 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@179c285: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@179c285]; startup date [Tue Apr 17 23:51:49 BOT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 17, 2012 11:51:49 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Apr 17, 2012 11:51:49 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@179c285]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@16a786
Apr 17, 2012 11:51:49 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [jdbc.properties]
Apr 17, 2012 11:51:49 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@16a786: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,propertyConfigurer,dataSource,UserDao,sessionFactory]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/MappingException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:596)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:365)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.apress.flexjava.usermanager.business.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/MappingException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:883)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:270)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/MappingException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.MappingException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: You're missing jars at runtime, or have a version conflict, etc. The error tells you what class def is causing the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.hibernate.MappingException
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>       ... 38 more

Indicates that you are missing the Hibernate libraries from your project. Try adding the following to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
</dependency>
```